# Accept rate not available in the 2.0 API

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v2

Would it be possible to add the `accept_rate` field to *both* the `user` and `shallow_user` objects?

For example, using the 1.0 API, I can see that Jon Skeet has an accept rate of 95%.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/22656

And unless I'm looking in the wrong place, I can't seem to find it in a similar 2.0 API query.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/22656/?site=stackoverflow

Comment: @Jonathan. The reason I specifically mentioned wanting it in the `shallow_user` object is because question queries (among many others) also include the `shallow_user`, and my thinking was that it saves another API call to the _full_ user object _just_ to retrieve the `accept_rate`. And yes, I understand the above query returns a full user object, it was only meant to be an example :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whelp, that was an oversight.

`accept_rate` should now be returned on both `user` and `shallow_user`.  Note that when insufficient data is available to calculate an accept rate, we don't return anything at all.

The exact rules for calculating accept rate are subject to change, but [currently documented here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).  The API returned accept rate should always match the site displayed value, making accommodations for caching on both ends.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. So, do I get `[bug]` credit for this one :)